# How to append column names into row and leave the column's value next to it?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'd like to append my dataframe with column names (which will be a date), and to leave its row value next to it. I started with this kind of dataframe:

```
Attribute | State | Metric | 2020-05-01 | 2020-05-02 | 2020-05-03 | ...
Attribute1| A     | 12     | 360        |  550       | 650        | ....
Attribute1| A     | 14     | 200        |  300       | 900        | ....
Attribute1| B     | 18     | 400        |  700       | 100        | ....
Attribute2| B     | 20     | 120        |  900       | 120        | ....
```

So I grouped by Attribute and State, made the sum of the rest and received:

```
Attribute | State | Metric | 2020-05-01 | 2020-05-02 | 2020-05-03 | ...
Attribute1| A     | sum    | sum        |  sum       | sum        | ....
Attribute1| B     | sum    | sum        |  sum       | sum        | ....
Attribute2| B     | sum    | sum        |  sum       | sum        | ....
```

And right now I need to change this table to fit pivot table in Excel, so I need to put those columns as rows, while maintaining the value. How to do this?

Desired output:

```
Attribute | State | Metric | Date       | ValueForDate 
Attribute1| A     | sum    | 2020-05-01 |  #       
Attribute1| A     | sum    | 2020-05-02 |  #       
Attribute1| A     | sum    | 2020-05-03 |  #
Attribute1| B     | sum    | 2020-05-01 |  #
.
.
.
```

Does anyone have a clue how to achieve this output? Thanks in advance and let me know in case my question is misunderstandable.

Comment: Have a look at `melt`, e.g. `df.melt(['Attribute','State','Metric'])`?

Comment: @QuangHoang thanks a lot, a little bit more complicated in my code, but yup!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using `melt`:

```
df = df.groupby(by=['Attribute', 'State'], as_index=False).sum()
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Attribute', 'State', 'Metric'], var_name='Date')
print(df)

    Attribute State  Metric        Date  value
0  Attribute1     A      26  2020-05-01    560
1  Attribute1     B      18  2020-05-01    400
2  Attribute2     B      20  2020-05-01    120
3  Attribute1     A      26  2020-05-02    850
4  Attribute1     B      18  2020-05-02    700
5  Attribute2     B      20  2020-05-02    900
6  Attribute1     A      26  2020-05-03   1550
7  Attribute1     B      18  2020-05-03    100
8  Attribute2     B      20  2020-05-03    120
```